# Set timeout for sessions

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session, timeout

I've read some others threads from here and outside, but nothing worked... I have a few `Sessions` like (login, column's value ...). And I want to set a time to the `Sessions` expires... I've tried:

```
Session.TimeOut = "60";
```

and also using the `web.cfg`

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I test the `Session` on every page_load like:

```
if(Session["login"] == null)
{
   Response.Redirect("/Login.aspx");
}
```

But it seems that the `Session` get lost in the middle of the navigation because after sometime (1min, 5min, 2min ....) It returns to the `login page`. What could be wrong here ?
I also read some articles about `Membership Authentication` but I couldn't get it =\
Thanks

Comment: Are you getting logged out and redirected to the login page because the session has actually expired.....?

Comment: Well, I think so, because what else could it be ? I tested the `Session` on every page if the session is empty I redirect to the login.aspx... What you have in mind ?

Comment: That's `seconds` , Not `minuts` ?

Comment: I hope somewhere in your code you're doing something like `Session["login"] = "somevalue"` so that the `["login"]` key is not null. Preferably after logging in.

Comment: I do it on the `login.aspx` ... Then when the `Sessions` expires, i redirect to the login page... Where I'll do this process again. Isn't that right ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you do not redirect to a different (sub)domain. On each domain the user will get a sepperate session. For example:

```
http://ww.mydomain.com
http://wwww.mydomain.com
```

have sepperate sessions.

Comment: Humm... I dont know answer this. I have two master pages and it's child pages... I Just redirect to these pages... How could I know this ? ;s
Thanks !

Comment: Look at your url in your browser.

Comment: The only thing that changes, is the name of the page. /xxx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will also lose the session once the application pool recycles. Check out this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx if you find anything useful that might help you with the problem.

I once had a similar problem, the session timeout was set to 60 minutes in the web.config but the session was still lost after like 20 minutes. Turned out to be a wrong setting in the IIS settings that caused the application pool to recycle and thus the session was gone.